# Classes and inaccessible members

Tags: c++, class, member, friend

I am having a hard time understanding how to fix this code I get the error message that both point Point::x & Point::y are inaccessible. How do I fix this?

```
class Point {

    int x, y;

public:
    Point(int u, int v) : x(u), y(v) {} 
    int getX() { return x; }
    int getY() { return y; }

    void setX(int newX) { x = newX; } 
    void setY(int newY) { y= newY; } 

};
 
int main() {
    Point p(5, 3); 
    std::cout << p.x << ' ' << p.y;//should print out 5 3
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not make them non-public? But better see comment by Anoop below...

Comment: Use getters `getX` and `getY` like `std::cout<< p.getX();` and `std::cout<<p.getY();` or you can even make `x` and `y` public but then that will defeat the purpose of having getters and setters.

Comment: `x` and `y` are indeed inaccessible (by default members are private). But accessors are defined.

Comment: @Yunnosch: that's precisely what the OP did ! What more do you want ???

Comment: So you can compile that without any problems? No includes needed to be added? @YvesDaoust

Comment: @Yunnosch: so ask that in your comment.

Comment: What did you think was the purpose of writing `getX`, `setX`, `getY`, and `setY`?

Comment: Aside: you might as well have `class Point { public: int x, y; };`

Comment: No. If the shown code is not an MRE I never list the details which I found to be missing. I always refer to the definition. @YvesDaoust Otherwise it turns much too often into a ping pong match. Also, the concept and process of making a MRE is a valuable tool to learn. Doing it right is so often all the debugging which is needed.

Comment: if this is the real full point class, I think it's better to use `struct Point{int x;int y;}` directly, wrap `x` and `y` into getter/setter doesn't provide any benefit.

Answer (score 4):

The **problem** is that the data members `x` and `y` are `private` by default for a **class type** defined using the keyword `class`(as opposed to keyword `struct`).

To **solve** the error you can use the getters `getX` and `getY` as shown below:

```
 std::cout << p.getX() << ' ' << p.getY();
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/MILTcz9eK).

---

Another option(less/not recommended) would be to make `x` and `y` public or use `struct` keyword but that would defeat the purpose of having getters and setters(`setX` and `setY`).

Answer (score 0):

Class members (as opposed to struct members) are private by default so you can't directly access `Point::x` and `Point::y` outside of the definition of `Point`; however, you have defined getters for those values which are public.